# javascript object instances, attribute values

Tags: javascript

I have created a DeformableShape object and creating instances of it via for loop. I am calling object's setPosition method and change its pivot property but values are updated for all instances... Say  I have  object A and I change it's pivot B object's pivot is changing too. What is wrong with the below code?

```
function DeformableShape(pivot, maxRadius, numSegment){
            this.pivot = pivot;
            this.maxRadius = maxRadius;
            this.numSegment = numSegment;
            this.path = new Path({
                fillColor : 'black',
                fullySelected: false,
                closed:true
            });

            this.path.add(this.pivot)
            for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment + 1; i++) {
                k = (i == 0) ? 0 : Math.random();
                var delta = new Point({
                    length: (maxRadius * 0.5) + (k * 10 * 0.5),
                    angle: (90 / this.numSegment) * i * -1
                });

                this.path.add({ x:delta.x + this.pivot.x , y:delta.y + this.pivot.y });

            }



        }

        DeformableShape.prototype = {
            iterate: function() {

            },

            setPosition:function(inX){

                this.pivot.x += inX;
                this.path.position.x = this.pivot.x;


            },

            collapse: function(){
                var segments = this.path.segments;
                var i = 5;
                for (var i = 0; i < this.numSegment + 2; i ++){
                    var tween = new TWEEN.Tween( segments[i].point )
                    .to( { x: this.pivot.x , y:this.pivot.y }, 2000 )
                    .easing( TWEEN.Easing.Circular.InOut )

                     tween.delay(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 300));
                     tween.start();
                }   
            }

        }


        // CREATE INSTANCES
        createDeformableShapes = function(){
            var center = new Point(400, 230)
            for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
                ds = new DeformableShape(center, 40, 5 );
                ds.setPosition(30)
                ds.collapse();
            }
        }
```

Comment: you set the same on all instance in that code. and ds is likely accidentally global, which means there's no way to access anything but the last created defoermableShape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and played with it a bit. The problem is that you set the same Point object as the pivot for all of them, each one correctly has a reference to that object (but still the same object). So when you change it for one, you change it for all.

The solution is create a new Point object as pivot for each :) Just put the creation of the center Point init inside the loop:

```
 createDeformableShapes = function(){
        for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
            var center = new Point(400, 230); //here
            ds = new DeformableShape(center, 40, 5 );
            ds.setPosition(30)
            ds.collapse();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is going to create 1 object, `ds`, which has an instanceof `DeformableShape`, and NOT 5 objects.

Comment: Incorrect! This WILL create 5 objects, do a few things with the object and then overwrite the "reference" in the next iteration. The PO didn't say they need to maintain a list of references! They're just doing things with the current object and throwing the reference away. Anyways, what you are talking about is out of the scope of the question. Thanks

Comment: You are correct, but for all intents and purposes, since the reference to those other 4 objects is lost, I don't see how this could be desired behaviour, especially since the 5 objects are identical. Thus I assumed that this would need amending, also.

Comment: Your thinking is rational. The first thing I did when I tried the OPs code was create a list to check each's values in the debugger. "but for all intents and purposes " I avoid making assumptions because maybe he wants to track the deformable objects in their constructor, maybe he doesn't care about tracking them, just create the object and draw it on an HTML 5 canvas, or create SVG elements for them (and that'll make them trackable if the elements are used as container of the data). Giving the immense search space, I can't make assumptions.

Comment: Yep totally agree. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You are overwriting `ds` every time you create a `new DeformableShape()`, and as another poster below suggested you are using the same Point object for each shape. Note that `ds` is also a global. If you want to loop and create the objects, store them in an array.

```
// CREATE INSTANCES
var createDeformableShapes = function(){
    var deformableShapes = [];
    for(var i=0; i < 5; i++){
            var center = new Point(400, 230)
        var ds = new DeformableShape(center, 40, 5 );
        ds.setPosition(30)
        ds.collapse();
        deformableShapes.push(ds);
    }
            return deformableShapes;
}
    // now you have an array of DeformableShapes in createDeformableShapes.
```

Comment: Agree. But might want to end that function with `return deformableShapes;`, otherwise the whole thing becomes kinda useless.

Comment: Thanks, missed his assignment of the function, have fixed.